# Is there a way to generate a new or populate existing resource group in a customized template

Tags: azure, templates, azure-devops, organization

I'm attempting to create a new organization in Azure DevOps via a custom ARM template. The only thing I can't figure out how to do is populating the resource group underneath the subscription section (or create new):

[image]

The template.json contains the following:

```
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "accountName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the Azure DevOps organization to be created."
            }
        },
        "rgLocation": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Resource group location"
            }
        },
        "Region": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Region"
            }
        },
        "resourceGroup": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Resource group location"
            }
        }
    },
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
  "name": "string",
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {
    "tagName1": "tagValue1",
    "tagName2": "tagValue2"
  },
  "scope": "string",
  "properties": {
    "debugSetting": {
      "detailLevel": "string"
    },
    "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
      "scope": "string"
    },
    "mode": "string",
    "onErrorDeployment": {
      "deploymentName": "string",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "parameters": {},
    "parametersLink": {
      "contentVersion": "string",
      "uri": "string"
    },
    "template": {},
    "templateLink": {
      "contentVersion": "string",
      "id": "string",
      "queryString": "string",
      "relativePath": "string",
      "uri": "string"
    }
  },
  "resourceGroup": "string",
  "subscriptionId": "string"
  
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.VisualStudio/account",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('accountName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                "operationType": "Create",
                "accountName": "[parameters('accountName')]",
                "rgLocation": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
                "resourceGroup": "[parameters('resourceGroup')]",
                "Region": "[parameters('Region')]"

            },
            "resources": []
        }
    ]
}
```

and the parameters.json contains:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "accountName": {
        "value": "whatever123"
      },
      "rgLocation": {
        "value": "Central US"
      },
      "Region": {
        "value": "Central US"
      },
      "resourceGroup": {
        "value": "newRG"
      }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this? I would like to have automation in place to be able to execute this in a pipeline.

Attempted adding the deployment scope to target resource group via JSON but was unsuccessful in populating an existing RG in the default subscription. I have not attempted creating a new RG within the template.

Comment: Spoke to a Microsoft support rep who said they have removed the ability to automate this as they were having issues with people automatically standing up subscriptions, then using the agents assigned to these subs to mine crypto.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there any way to do this? I would like to have automation in place to be able to execute this in a pipeline.**

*Yes, we can create Azure DevOps Organization either by Manual or using ARM Template. By using ARM Template, you have to specify the Resource and organization name as a parameter*.

**Upon ARM template ready here is the** [tutorial](https://purple.telstra.com/blog/step-by-step-using-azure-devops-services-to-deploy-arm-templates-with-ci-cd-part-2?_ga=2.34389993.937502633.1673411698-1842015535.1673411698) **to implement the automation process via DevOps.**

NOTE:  Using Azure DevOps Services to deploy ARM templates with CI/ CD [refer](https://purple.telstra.com.au/blog/step-by-step-using-azure-devops-services-to-deploy-arm-templates-with-ci-cd-part-1#:%7E:text=Enabling%20deployment%20of%20ARM%20Template,page,%20click%20on%20New%20Pipeline.)

replicated with source template and able to add existing resource group from subscription.

```
{
     "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "accountName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the Azure DevOps organization to be created."
            }
        },
        "rgLocation": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Resource group location"
            }
        },
        "Region": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Region"
            }
        },
        "resourceGroup": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Resource group location"
            }
        }
    },
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
  "name": "string",
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {
    "tagName1": "tagValue1",
    "tagName2": "tagValue2"
  },
  "scope": "string",
  "properties": {
    "debugSetting": {
      "detailLevel": "string"
    },
    "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
      "scope": "string"
    },
    "mode": "string",
    "onErrorDeployment": {
      "deploymentName": "string",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "parameters": {},
    "parametersLink": {
      "contentVersion": "string",
      "uri": "string"
    },
    "template": {},
    "templateLink": {
      "contentVersion": "string",
      "id": "string",
      "queryString": "string",
      "relativePath": "string",
      "uri": "string"
    }
  },
  "resourceGroup": "string",
  "subscriptionId": "string",
  "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.VisualStudio/account",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('accountName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                "operationType": "Create",
                "accountName": "[parameters('accountName')]",
                "rgLocation": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
                "resourceGroup": "[parameters('resourceGroup')]",
                "Region": "[parameters('Region')]"

            },
            "resources": []
        }
    ]
}
```

upon adding parameters with existing resource group by selecting existing resource group and futher params.
[image]

[image]